# Making an RSVP form.. How do I make required fields not required based on dropdown?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I built an RSVP form for a wedding site I'm doing for a friend and I have a few drop downs in the form for attending on Friday and Saturday and for the meal option. Right now, all the fields are required, but I want to make it so the meal option drop down is only required if the person selects "yes" to attending on Friday and Saturday. So essentially the meal option drop down should only be required if the person is coming to the wedding. How do I do this in PHP?

Here is my form...

```
        <div class="form">

                <div class="validation">
                    <p>Oops! Please correct the highlighted fields...</p>
                </div>

                <div class="success">
                    <p>Thanks for your response!</p>
                </div>

                <form action="javascript:;" method="post" id="rsvp_form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <p>
                            <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <select name="friday" id="friday">
                              <option value="">Friday Dinner?</option>
                              <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                              <option value="No">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </p>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <p>
                            <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" />
                        </p>    
                        <p>
                            <select name="saturday" id="saturday">
                              <option value="">Saturday Wedding?</option>
                              <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                              <option value="No">No</option>
                            </select>
                        </p>                        

                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <p>
                            <label for="rsvp_email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" name="rsvp_email" id="rsvp_email" />
                        </p>                            

                        <p>
                            <select name="meal_choice" id="meal_choice">
                              <option value="">Meal Choice...</option>
                              <option value="Short Ribs">Short Ribs</option>
                              <option value="Red Snapper Fillet">Red Snapper Fillet</option>
                              <option value="Stuffed Poblano Pepper">Stuffed Poblano Pepper (Vegetarian)</option>
                            </select>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" class="button" value="RSVP" />
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my PHP script that is working...

```
<?php


// Extract form contents
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$rsvp_email = $_POST['rsvp_email'];
$invite_code = $_POST['invite_code'];
$friday = $_POST['friday'];
$saturday = $_POST['saturday'];
$meal_choice = $_POST['meal_choice'];

// Validate email address
function valid_email($str) {
    return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $str)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}

// Return errors if present
$errors = "";

if($first_name =='') { $errors .= "first_name,"; }
if($last_name =='') { $errors .= "last_name,"; }
if(valid_email($rsvp_email)==FALSE) { $errors .= "rsvp_email,"; }
if($friday =='') { $errors .= "friday,"; }
if($saturday =='') { $errors .= "saturday,"; }
if($meal_choice =='') { $errors .= "meal_choice,"; }



// Send email
if($errors =='') {

    $headers =  'From:  <no-reply@website.com>'. "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: '.$rsvp_email.'' . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $email_subject = "RSVP Form: $first_name $last_name";
    $message="First Name: $first_name \n\nLast Name: $last_name \n\nRSVP Email: $rsvp_email \n\nAttending Friday: $friday \n\nAttending Saturday: $saturday \n\nMeal Choice: $meal_choice";

    mail($to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "true";

} else {
    echo $errors;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if either `$friday` or `$saturday` are given then do the check for meal. If both are not entered then there will not be a check for meal

```
if($first_name =='') { $errors .= "first_name,"; }
if($last_name =='') { $errors .= "last_name,"; }
if(valid_email($rsvp_email)==FALSE) { $errors .= "rsvp_email,"; }
if($friday =='') { $errors .= "friday,"; }
if($saturday =='') { $errors .= "saturday,"; }
if( $friday != '' || $saturday != '') {
   if($meal_choice =='') { $errors .= "meal_choice,"; }
}
```

Comment: So where would I put this line of code? After the form validation and before the send email starts?

Comment: replace the current meal check with the code in the answer, or just surround it with the if statement like i have.

Comment: I'm still getting the red box around the meal option and it's throwing the error.

Comment: are you doing validation on the client side? You have not mentioned how you are doing validation on the client side if you are. Reedit your question to contain the relevant parts of your validation process

Comment: I'm not doing any other validation except this php.. At least I don't think so. If I remove the line for the "if($meal_choice =='') { $errors .= "meal_choice,"; }" for the meal option, then the form processes without the validation check.. So I guess it's just the PHP server side.

Comment: what is turning your meal box red?

Comment: I got it working.. I had to put in 'No' so it knows not to validate for when the user selects "No" in the drop down field. Thanks so much!